# How to convert numpy ndarray values to probability values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

The following results are numpy ndarray scores from linear regression[y = Wx + b].

```
scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.h_drop, W, b, name='scores')
~ ~ .....
all_scores = np.zeros(shape=(0,len(label_dict))) 
~~...    
all_scores = np.concatenate((all_scores, batch_scores) , axis=0)
```

[image: numpy ndarray]
  [image: numpy ndarray description]
**How do I change above numpy ndarray values to ndarray probability values ?**

Desired results:

```
      col0    col1      col2     col3   col4    col5 

Row1 0.02  |   0.123 | 0.678 | 0.067 | 0.0987 | 0.1089   : Sum(col0~5) = 1 
~
```

Comment: probabilities of what?

Comment: I'd like to convert result values' each value to probability values like above 'Desired results' [ all_scores : ndarray values ] .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to apply to softmax function:

f(x) = e^x_i / sum_j e^x_j

This will transform values in any range to a vector that sums to one, which can be interpreted as probabilities. A TF function that does this is tf.nn.softmax.